# Django urls.py query

Tags: django, django-urls

I want that upon browsing a link from my dashboard page, the url should be `/dashboard/link`. 
When I write `url(r'dashboard/inbox/','apps.dashboard.views.inbox', name = 'grabhalo_inbox'),` it does reads my `views` argument provided.

Instead when I write `url(r'inbox/','apps.dashboard.views.inbox', name = 'grabhalo_inbox'),` I get the expected output , but the url is `/inbox`. What I want is `/dashboard/inbox`.

Where i'm going wrong?

Here is my root **urls.py** file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^',include('apps.auth.urls')),
    (r'^',include('apps.dashboard.urls')),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here is my dashboard.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'dashboard/','apps.dashboard.views.dashboard', name = 'grabhalo_dashboard'),
    url(r'sent/','apps.dashboard.views.sent', name = 'grabhalo_sent'),
    url(r'inbox/','apps.dashboard.views.inbox', name = 'grabhalo_inbox'),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `^` and `$` (start and end of a string) to your `dashboard/` url regex:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dashboard/$','apps.dashboard.views.dashboard', name = 'grabhalo_dashboard'),
    url(r'^sent/$','apps.dashboard.views.sent', name = 'grabhalo_sent'),
    url(r'^dashboard/inbox/$','apps.dashboard.views.inbox', name = 'grabhalo_inbox'),
    )
```

Then, `http://mydomain.com/dashboard/` will be handled by `apps.dashboard.views.dashboard` view,  `http://mydomain.com/dashboard/inbox/` - by `apps.dashboard.views.inbox`.